# Is it possible to train a perceptron to tell if a picture is a dog or cat?

Tags: image-recognition, perceptron

I know perceptron is a linear classifier that tells linearly separable binary class data, such as iris setosa vs. iris versicolor via their sepal's length and width.

I'd just like to know if I have 2 groups of photos, one is for dog and the other is for cat, is it possible to train a perceptron to tell if a picture is a dog or cat?

[image]

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by "iris photos, one is for dog and the other is for cat", if the iris dataset is not a dataset that contains photos of dog and cat? I guess that's a typo, but I just wanted you to clarify this.

Comment: @nbro Updated, thanks for your reminder.

Comment: I would say in general no, but it depends on the data. If all pictures of dogs have a certain colour etc. and all cats a different colour then they can certainly be separated. A single perceptron is not going to be able to detect shapes though, that's what conv nets are for

Comment: It probably is possible but will have 80-90% accuracy while a CNN should get 98% + accuracy.

Comment: If you really want to know just follow this tutorial https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-to-classify-photos-of-dogs-and-cats/ and make the model a vanilla perception. You'll run into a couple snags though. The perceptron requires a fixed-size set of weights so you'll need to resale the image to something know if you really want to try this.